# Getting "Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: ''" when creating a SP in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote this SP in MySQL version: 8.0.34 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) running in docker

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SearchEvents`(IN P_team_id INT, IN P_event_name VARCHAR(255), IN P_event_start_date DATE, IN P_event_end_date DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE mainQuery VARCHAR(1000);
    SET @mainQuery = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE 1';

    IF P_team_id IS NOT NULL AND P_team_id <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(mainQuery, ' AND team_id = ', P_team_id);
    END IF;

    IF P_event_name IS NOT NULL AND P_event_name <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(mainQuery, ' AND (event_name_en LIKE "%', P_event_name, '%" OR event_name_ar LIKE "%', P_event_name, '%")');
    END IF;

    IF P_event_start_date IS NOT NULL AND P_event_start_date <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(mainQuery, ' AND event_start_date >= \'', P_event_start_date,'\'');
    END IF;

    IF P_event_end_date IS NOT NULL AND P_event_end_date <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(mainQuery, ' AND event_end_date <= \'', P_event_end_date,'\'');
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @mainQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

and when it's executed `call ssgg.SearchEvents(1, '', NULL, NULL);`  it should return all events related to team 1. However, the following error is returned `Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value: ''`

I tried calling it using actual dates `call ssgg.SearchEvents(1, '', '2023-01-01', '2023-12-31');` which should get last year's events but got the same result. Any advise?

**UPDATE**

as per suggestions I removed the comparison of `P_event_start_date` & `P_event_end_date` with `''`.

Now a new error was returned

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1`.

I am calling the SP like this `call ssgg.SearchEvents(1, '', NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Provide some sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3). PS. Empty string is wrong value for DATE really..

Comment: When comparing date with string, string is converted to date hence the error. The comparison/conversion will _always_ take place regardless of the value passed. Remove the  `P_event_start_date <> ''` check.

Comment: @SalmanA I did as u suggested and a new error was returned  ```16:55:06 call ssgg.SearchEvents(1, '', NULL, NULL) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 0.0012 sec```

Comment: Looks like the generated SQL has a syntax error. Can you SELECT the mainQuery instead of executing it? See what the result of concatenation is.

Comment: @SalmanA you are right it had a syntax error indeed. Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a DATE type parameter like `P_event_start_date` and `P_event_end_date`, it doesn't make sense to check for an empty string ('') as it's not a valid representation for a date in MySQL. Hence, it's more appropriate to only check for `NULL` for date parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchEvents`(IN P_team_id INT, IN P_event_name VARCHAR(255), IN P_event_start_date DATE, IN P_event_end_date DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE mainQuery VARCHAR(1000);
    SET @mainQuery = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE 1';

    IF P_team_id IS NOT NULL AND P_team_id <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(@mainQuery, ' AND team_id = ', P_team_id);
    END IF;

    IF P_event_name IS NOT NULL AND P_event_name <> '' THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(@mainQuery, ' AND (event_name_en LIKE "%', P_event_name, '%" OR event_name_ar LIKE "%', P_event_name, '%")');
    END IF;

    IF P_event_start_date IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(@mainQuery, ' AND event_start_date >= \'', P_event_start_date,'\'');
    END IF;

    IF P_event_end_date IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @mainQuery = CONCAT(@mainQuery, ' AND event_end_date <= \'', P_event_end_date,'\'');
    END IF;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @mainQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

**[See this db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/MWlmt_kO)**